# How do you pass params into another Xacro file via xacro:include? How does the other Xacro file receive that input?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, xacro, include, namespace

How do you use `xacro:macro` and `arg` to include 2 of the same robot in your URDF? I'm using args for each Xacro file to read the suffix. Because it's in the global namespace, I can't reassign the suffix arg. This results in a conflicting namespace. "Error: link 'slide_1/base_link' is not unique."

Also, the urdf.xacro file I'm including has a macro as well, with material tags inside to keep it local. However, running this macro 2 times, the materials get declared multiple times. "Error: material 'aluminum' is not unique." *I have an inconvenient way of solving this by passing a global arg and wrapping each material declaration around an if statement so the materials are only declared once at the top level xacro. Not pretty.*

```
<xacro:macro name="full_assembly" params="suffix">
  <xacro:arg name="suffix" default="${suffix}" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find pkg)/urdf/single_assembly.urdf.xacro" />
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:property name="suffix_1" value="_1" />
<xacro:property name="suffix_2" value="_2" />
<xacro:full_assembly suffix="${suffix_1}" />
<xacro:full_assembly suffix="${suffix_2}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ns` tag in the `xacro:include`.

Resources

- ROS Wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Including_other_xacro_files
- Xacro Repo: https://github.com/ros/xacro/wiki#xacroinclude